# How to count number of nodes in a linked-list ?Why does the output show the count of nodes as '2'?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have written a c program to find the number of nodes in a link list. But the problem arises because the value of count that I am printing comes out to be '2'.

My exact output looks like->

**NUMBER OF NODES ARE 2**

What am I doing wrong here?

```
//the code for the program is here:-

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void create(int a[],int n)
{
 struct node *t,*last;
 first=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 first->data=a[0];
 first->next=0;
 last=first;
 int i;
 for(i=1;i<n;i++)
 {
  t=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  t->data=a[i];
  t->next=NULL;
  last->next=t;
  last=first;
 }
}

void count(struct node *p) //function to count number of nodes
{
 int count=0;
 while(p!=NULL)
 {
  count++;
  p=p->next;
 }
 printf("Number of nodes are %d ",count);
}

int main()
{
 int a[]={1,2,3,4};
 create(a,4);
 count(first);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: an indent width of 1 char will be lost when working with variable width fonts.  Suggest using 4 spaces per indent level

Comment: OT: regarding: `first=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` and `t=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the casts.  2) When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` and/or `realloc()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) the allocated memory is not passed to `free()` before exiting the program, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node *next;
}*first=NULL`  Do NOT hide pointers.  Rather separate the struct definition from an instance of the struct.  This results in more code clarity and greater flexibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in the loop within the function `create`

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
```

you mean

```
last = last->next;
```

instead of

```
last=first;
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to declare the pointer to the head node as global and when functions depend on global variables.

Also the user can pass to the function the number of elements of an array equal to 0. Also allocation of memory can fail.

I would declare the function the following way

```
size_t create( struct node **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    // if the list is not empty free its nodes
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        struct node *current = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( current );
    }

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n && ( *head = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) ) ) != NULL; i++ )
    {
        ( *head )->data = a[i];
        ( *head )->next = NULL;

        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    return i;
}
```

And call the function like

```
size_t n = create( &first, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
```

In this case the function returns the number of created nodes in the list.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

size_t create( struct node **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    // if the list is not empty free its nodes
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        struct node *current = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( current );
    }

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n && ( *head = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) ) ) != NULL; i++ )
    {
        ( *head )->data = a[i];
        ( *head )->next = NULL;

        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    return i;
}

void output( const struct node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;

    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t n = create( &head, a, N );

    printf( "There are %zu nodes in the list\n", n );

    printf( "They are " );

    output( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
There are 4 nodes in the list
They are 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
```